# how to manually insert string with html codes in wp_posts table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm doing migration going to wordpress and needed manual inserting of data to wp_posts table. In inserting the data, I'm using mysql_real_escape_string but html attributes being inserted with additional \" 
example :

```
#Original
<img src="imge.jpg" alt="abcde fghij">

#Inserted to wp_posts using mysql_real_escape_string
<img src="\"imge.jpg"\" alt="\"abcde fghij"\">
```

This is bad and makes the images not working. So I need help of how to insert data to wp_posts.post_content in a way that wordpress acceptable.

Comment: additional note : if you installed wordpress and check existing post, you will see html tags are not escape

Comment: have you tried to use singe quote?? <img src='imge.jpg' alt='abcde fghij'>

Comment: Hi Bee, thanks for leaving message, anyway I already tried that but still the same issue. I also tried removing the quotes but we all know its not good practice and given me new issue with attributes alt - since no quotes browser just use the first word in alt attributes. I wonder how wordpress insert their data to wp_posts table hmm.. hope I can decode it.

Answer (score 0):

**have you tried to use singe quote?? 
try this..**

```
<img src='imge.jpg' alt='abcde fghij'>
```

Comment: Single quotes are escaped too, so this doesn't change anything really.

Answer (score 0):

PDO way of saving the data fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this function for adding the image content and other.

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => '#Enter the title#',
 'post_content'  => '#Enter the Content#'
,'post_status'   => 'publish',
 'post_author'   => 1
);
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

It will not add any slice or anything else.

Thanking you.