# How to edit mySQL wp_posts table from plugin php in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I have a need to change a plugin that creates/edits entries to the wp_posts table. Currently, it is lacking in that it cannot target some specific fields. I am endeavoring to edit the plugin so I can change these fields as well with the plugin. Specifics below.

How would I generally target this table then create/edit entries?

I have in mind something like this, which was copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31404008/1934286).:

```
$my_post = array(
   'post_title'    => '#Enter the title#',
   'post_content'  => '#Enter the Content#',
   'post_status'   => 'publish',
   'post_author'   => 1
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

I assume this is possible because the plugin I'm hoping to change already makes changes to the wp_posts table. How do I do this? I have programming experience in C#, but my PHP and WP knowledge is severely lacking. I assume there's a few [WordPress key functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) that I'm looking for, but I simply don't know what they are or how to find them (I might be searching for the wrong terms). `wp_insert_post()` looks very promising, but [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) seems to imply that it won't work for my specific needs.

---

**Specifics**

I'm using a great plugin called [Really Simple CSV importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/) (RSC), which allows you to create/update posts with a csv. It seems to be able to target nearly every field (e.g. `post_title`, `post_id`, `post_parent`, `post_content`, `_wp_page_template`, etc.). This is quite a boon if you have to create hundreds of pages regularly (which I do).

The problem is that it won't target two specific fields, which are titled `group_access` and `tag_list`. I put those fields as columns in my csv, but they are not added to the mySQL database, and thus are not changed on the site. I believe these fields are specific to a plugin called [iMember360](https://imember360.com/), which is a plugin that ties into an [InfusionSoft](https://www.infusionsoft.com/) account.

Naturally, I've tried contacting RSC support, but have received no replies at all. I've spoken to iMember360 support at length, and the best they can give me without doing the work themselves is that they use the action hook `import_end` to make changes to the table, so if RSC is not using it, then it won't affect those fields. They also say that iMember360 has an import/export function, but it is only for the plugin's specific features, and ties in with the WordPress XML import/export feature. Clearly, this RSC plugin does not do that.

Regardless of these limitations, it seems to me like if the field exists in the table, then you should be able to edit it, so I tend to think that the RSC plugin is simply lacking in this functionality, probably only targeting WP default fields only.

---

**What I've tried:**

I have tried editing the plugin PHP directly, with the assumption that the plugin simply does not have an entry for the `group_access` and `tag_list` fields.

One of the PHP files contained:

```
// (string, comma separated) name of post tags
$post_tags = $h->get_data($this,$data,'post_tags');
if ($post_tags) {
    $post['post_tags'] = $post_tags;
}
```

I simply copied and pasted it right above it and changed `post_tags` to `group_access`. It didn't work.

I also found, and added to:

```
$attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $mime_type ,
            'post_parent'    => $this->postid ,
            'post_author'    => $this->post->post_author ,
            'post_title'     => $title ,
            'post_content'   => $content ,
            'post_excerpt'   => $excerpt ,
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'menu_order'     => $this->media_count + 1,
////////// added
            'group_access'   => $group_access ,
            'tag_list'   => $tag_list ,
//////
        );
```

That didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to edit the `wp_posts` table that I know of. The first is with the `wp_update_post()` and `wp_insert_post()` functions. These are typical WP functions that are used like any others. You just have to pass the correct parameters. For example:

```
$my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $updatePostID, // User defined variable; the post id you want to update.
      'post_title'   => 'Update Title',
      'post_content' => 'Update Content', 
  );
// Update the post into the database
$post_id = wp_update_post( $my_post, true ); // Returns 0 if no error; returns post id if there was an error.

// Check if table was updated without error. For debugging. Remove from your code if it all works, before publishing.
if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
    $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

Simply pass an array with the predefined field names to the functions and they will then run correctly. The update function is for updates, naturally, and the insert function creates new table entries (rows). There is a limitation, however. These two functions will only operate on the WP predefined fields. So, if your table contains some custom fields, then you will have to use the `$wpdb` class.

The other way to update your mySQL tables from WordPress is to use the `$wpdb` class directly. This class is far more expansive than the `wp_update_post()` and `wp_insert_post()` functions. The first difference is that it can edit many other mySQL tables, not just the `wp_posts` table. It can also edit non-WP fields. For example:

```
global $wpdb; // This calls the use of the class. I actually do not think this is necessary, but I do it anyway.
$dbresult = $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, // Returns 0 if no errors. Post ID if errors occurred. 
            // Notice posts instead of wp-posts. Prefixes are not necessary with this class.
     ['post_title' => 'Update Title', 
      'post_content' => 'Update Content', 
      'custom_field' => $customField, ], // User defined table column and variable.
     ['ID' => $updatePostID, ]); // User defined variable; the post id.
if (false === $dbresult) {
    echo 'An error occurred while updating...'; 
    $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
}
```

I'm not very familiar with either of these options, but there seems to a massive difference in the width of functionality, so there may be considerations you should take before using one over the other. I've asked a question to that end: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/259043/38365 One [reply](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/259050/38365) says:

> Downsides of `$wpdb` are that you do need to know SQL and you need to be conscious of normal data sanitization and when to use `prepare()` and what functions already prepare your statement which are hardly downsides at all. The `$wpdb` Class is by nature more powerful than any of the default WordPress functions because *you* have access to *all* the data, custom or not, assuming you know the proper SQL to get, modify, or remove it.
>
> **TL;DR** `$wpdb` is more powerful but less friendly and forgiving.

That makes sense to me. Basically, don't fiddle with $wpdb unless you know what you are doing or absolutely have to.